# How do I add a menu item to the share menu in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, menu

I'm just getting into iOS development, but something I'm going to have to do early on is add a button to the system menus like how Dropbox has added its button when interacting with email attachments.

This application will be for video so adding a button on the share menu for quicktime players would be ideal.

I've scoured the documentation and have only found the UIMenuItem class. Is this what I want or is there another way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

1. Set project-info.plist -> add new item (UTExportedTypeDeclarations)

   ```
   <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
   <array>
   <dict>
       <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
       <array>
           <string>com.apple.quicktime-movie</string>
       </array>
       <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
       <string>com.company.project</string>
       <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
       <dict/>
   </dict>
   </array>
   ```
2. Coding your ButtonClick event in .m file

   ```
   -(IBAction)actionClick:(id)sender{

       UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController = 
             [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:
                                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:MOVIE_FILE_PATH]];
       documentController.delegate = self;
       documentController.UTI = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
       [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero 
                                              inView:self.view 
                                            animated:YES];
   }
   ```